# Почему механизм событий требует, чтобы параметр sender имел тип Object?

Tags: c#, события, clr

Данный вопрос всплыл при прочтении Рихтера. Он аргументирует это следующим высказыванием:

> Многих удивляет, почему механизм событий требует, чтобы параметр sender имел
> тип Object. Вообще-то, поскольку MailManager — единственный тип, реализующий
> события с объектом NewMailEventArgs, было бы разумнее использовать следующий
> прототип метода обратного вызова:
> void MethodName(MailManager sender, NewMailEventArgs e);
> Причиной того, что параметр sender имеет тип Object, является наследование.
> Что произойдет, если MailManager задействовать в качестве базового класса для
> создания класса SmtpMailManager? В методе обратного вызова придется в прототипе задать параметр sender как SmtpMailManager, а не MailManager, но этого
> делать нельзя, так как тип SmtpMailManager просто наследует событие NewMail.
> Поэтому код, ожидающий от SmtpMailManager информацию о событии, все равно
> будет вынужден приводить аргумент sender к типу SmtpMailManager. Иначе говоря,
> приведение все равно необходимо, поэтому параметр sender с таким же успехом
> можно объявить с типом Object.

Вопрос: Может кто-то привести пример кода показывающий, что да действительно объект sender должен иметь тип *Object*, а не *MailManager*.